# how to change the color of the entire excel sheet when exported in ag grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

How to change the color of the whole excel sheet when exporting in a grid ag grid, for example I want the whole excel sheet to have a white background, or gray etc. Is this possible and how?

```
function processCellStyle(params) {
        return {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' // Cambiamos el color de fondo de la celda
        };
```

`gridRef?.current.api?.exportDataAsExcel({ processCellStyle: processCellStyle });`

I thought it could be done this way but it doesn't work

output example
[image]